# Sails js bcrypt instalación

Tags: nodejs, npm, sailsjs

Saludos. Alguien podría decirme porque obtengo estos errores cuando intento realizar la instalación de bcrypt? Uso Windows 10[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

El camino fácil es cambiar del módulo npm "bcrypt" a bycryptjs o bcrypt-nodejs. Es exactamente la misma API, pero JavaScript puro, por lo que no hay que lidiar con complementos nativos.

```
npm install --save bcryptjs && npm uninstall --save bcrypt
```